# Can I fit a desktop processor in a 4U rack?

Tags: rack

Most desktop processors these days include the fan&heatsink attached to it. Can I expect that to fit in a 4U rack? For example, is a 4U rack considered a tower when it comes to fitting components in it?

Comment: Im not going to mark this as an answer but there are problems with fitting desktop heat sinks in rack cases. This is because the airflow for a desktop heat sink is pulling air from above the chip whereas a heat sink for a rack usually has a lot of fans pushing air thru the rack. 

As far as a desktop processor, the processor and heat sink are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to fit a standard ATX motherboard with desktop CPU/heatsink combo in a 4U server chassis.  1U or 1RU (rack unit) = 1.75 inches so 4U = 7 inches tall.  That will give you an idea of how tall your components can be depending on rack chassis chosen.